# displaying images from database (mysql) based on id in node js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I have an html that uses node js. I already can ulpoad the image to database and I want to display an image whose url is stored in the database, and the image is stored in file uploads in my data. in view.ejs i want display image base on id.

my data base is like this

[image]

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');

var connection = require('./config/db');
var session = require('express-session');
var SQLiteStore = require('connect-sqlite3')(session);

global.store = new SQLiteStore;
var app = express();

var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use("/files", serveIndex(__dirname + "/uploads"));
app.use("/files", express.static(__dirname + "/uploads"));


var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var id_photo = uuidv1();

global.appRoot = __dirname;

var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
},
filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + id_photo + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
})

var upload = multer({
storage: storage,
fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
    if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
        req.fileValidationError = "Only Image Allowed";
        return callback(null, false, req.fileValidationError)
    }
    callback(null, true)
}
}).any();

app.use(upload);
connection.init();
module.exports = app;
```

**upload_galery.js (controller)**

```
var connection = require('../../config/db');

function Todo() {
this.selectGalery = function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.query.id;
    var toast = req.query.toast;
    if (id != null) {
        detailGalery(req, res, next);
        return;
    }
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
        con.query('SELECT * FROM galerys order by modified_at desc', function(err, rows) {
            con.release();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
                if (toast != null) {
                    if (toast == 'add') {
                        res.render('ulpoad_galery/index', { obj: obj, message: 'Add Data Success' });
                    } else if (toast == 'edit') {
                        res.render('upload_galery/index', { obj: obj, message: 'Update Data Success' });
                    } else {
                        res.render('upload_galery/index', { obj: obj, message: 'Delete Data Success' });
                    }
                } else {
                    res.render('upload_galery/index', { obj: obj, message: null });
                }
            }
        });
    });
};

function detailGalery(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.query.id;
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query('SELECT * FROM galerys WHERE id = "' + id + '" order by modified_at desc', function(err, rows) {
            con.release();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
                res.render('upload_galery/view', { obj: obj });
            }
        });
    });
};
}
module.exports = new Todo();
```

**upload_galery.js (routes)**

```
var upload_galery = require('./../../controllers/web/upload_galery');

module.exports = {
configure: function(app) {
    app.route('/UploadGalery/Index').get(upload_galery.selectGalery);
    app.route('/UploadGalery/Add').get(upload_galery.insertGalery);

}
};
```

**view.ejs**

```
<div class="x_content">
                        <% obj.forEach(function (galery) { %>
                            <form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Motor Type : 
                                      </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <!-- <input type="text" id="first-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"> -->
                                        <label class="view-label col-md-7" for="first-name"><%= galery.motor_type %></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                    <div class="img"><img src='"http://192.168.xx.xxx:8080 + <%= galery.image1 %>"' width="400px" height="250px" id="img">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                            <% }) %>
                    </div>
```

but i cant display the image, can anybody help me? thank you..

Comment: Have you checked if the images are being saved in your File System and are being served independently?

Comment: Were you able to display a known (not uploaded) image with your application. Leave out all upload and database stuff and start reproducing the problem bit by bit. In the moment I fear not many people are likely to help, since you post a little too much code. I suggest to read about this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve